# Apache Ignite Limiting Connection to Persistent Store

Tags: spring, mongodb, ignite

Apache Ignite is currently creating multiple connections to the persistent store (Mongo). Is there a way to configure the cache's to use the same Mongo connection instead of spawning new ones?

I have looked through the documentation and api's but was not able to find ways to configure the way connections to stores are made.

Comment: It's all about your configuration. How do you access Mongo? I suppose you have implemented custom CacheStoreAdapter?

Comment: I have, I believe I have found the answer which is you can limit the number of connections made through the MongoClient